# Monte Carlo Rejection Sampling

Tags: statistics, monte-carlo

I have the function which I am trying to use calculate monte carlo estimate on using rejection sampling.

$f(x) = \int_2^\infty x^4 \sin(\pi(x+1)) e^{-x^2/2}dx$

My initial thought was that I could first limit the bounds for intergration to $\int_2^{10}$ since the function decreases to 0 quickly after x=4. Then I thought I could form a box around the function around the function and generate uniform points from that box and reject if they fall outside of the function. The rejection algorithm would looks something like

1. generate $x\sim U(2,10)$
2. Generate $y\sim U(-2,.5)$ (encloses min and max of function on the given range)
3. accept if y < f(x) or else go back to 1

However I am running into issues here since the function does crosses the y axis, I'm not sure what I am doing is correct. After I am running 40000 samples, I get an mean of 6.19, when I know the true value is about -0.85.

Is the approach I am taking somewhat correct, or am I thinking about this wrong. Below is my code and a plot I made of the rejection / accept region based on the simulations that seems wrong to me since its not actually capturing the true function.

```
Mp = .5
Mm = -2
B=40000
x =runif(B,2,10)
y=runif(B,Mm,Mp)
acc = y <=(x^4)*(sin(pi*(x+1)))*exp(-x^(2)/2)
mean(x[acc])
var(x[acc])


plot(x, y, pch=".", col="red")
points(x[acc], y[acc], pch=".")
```

[accept / rejected points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGSXp.png)

Comment: Why not try this? X=normrnd(-2,1,1e7,1); I=mean(1/sqrt(2*pi)*(X+2).^4.*sin(pi*(X+3)));

Comment: Rejection sampling is for simulating draws from an arbitrary density using a density you can simulate from. This is importance sampling used to estimate an integral and what you are doing is not close.

Comment: @Stacker Can you give me more information on how I would go about implanting importance sampling if I am currently not close?

Comment: Yes, the most rudimentary way to do it would be to generate $X_1,...,X_n$ on the interval [2,10] and then calculate $\frac{10-2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(X_i)$. Less rudimentary would be to use rejection sampling with importance sampling via $\int \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}f(x)dx$ where $f(x)$ is a specially chosen density that can be simulated using rejection sampling or another method. But I had a question, why is the integral $-.85$? Based on a plot of the function from 2 to 10 it looks like the definite integral should be positive. According to Wolfram it is about $1.85$.

Comment: Based on just using the integrate function in r (and checking wolframalpha `https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+2+to+10+of+%28x%5E4%29*%28sin%28pi*%28x%2B1%29%29%29*exp%28-x%5E%282%29%2F2%29`) I see the answer -0.85 Im not sure if I made a typo somewhere, but I don't see one. On the other hand, I was able to reproduce the most rudimentary method and reproduce -0.85, but how do I go about choosing a f(x) for this function. From what I see in a quick search it needs sort of mimic your function. Im not sure simpler other functions look like this (or if im understanding correctly)

Comment: Hmm thats a good question... Is it possible to split the integral into three parts from 2 to 3, 3, to 4, and 4 to 10. Then construct a function for each interval that approximates it on each interval with area under it equal to 1. For the second interval, for instance, you could try $-6(x-3)(x-4)$. It seems more trouble than its worth though

Comment: That makes sense to me, I can try it out and see how it works. Thanks for your help!